# gcloud gitlab ci Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied

Tags: gitlab-ci, gcloud

I've been hammering my head against the wall on this one and am just not sure what I'm missing. I'm trying to finish the configuration on a gitlab pipeline to push to a GKE cluster which I'm managing with helm. However, I keep getting a 403 permission denied when I try to pull the chart I have stored on Google's artifact registry, even though I've added what should be enough permissions for the service account I'm using.

I set up the service account as directed in the docs [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/index.html) , and here's the existing service account with permissions in the gcloud console:

[image]

In the last stage of the .gitlab-ci.yml I connect to the gcloud service account, get the response that shows the connection and existing image in the artifact registry, from there helm update the chart, but once I try to use helm to pull the chart I get a 403. I was basing the approach off of google's instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/helm/manage-charts).

gitlab-ci.yml last stage:

```
Deploy-Helm:
  stage: deploy
  image: kiwigrid/gcloud-kubectl-helm
  only: [dev-test]
  script:
    - echo "connecting to gcloud"
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account ${GCLOUD_SERVACCT} --key-file ${GCLOUD_SERVACCT_KEY}
    - gcloud config set project ${GCLOUD_PROJECT}
    - gcloud artifacts docker images list ${GCLOUD_REPO}
    - echo "pull chart from artifact reg"
    - helm pull oci://${GCLOUD_REPO}:0.1.0 \
      --version 1.0.0 \
      --untar
    - helm chart export helm-repo/project \
      --destination ./install
    - echo "Deploying Helm..."  
    - helm upgrade demotest ./install -n demotest -f ./install/values-test.yaml
```

In the pipeline, the flow shows that the service account connects, the chart image is listed correctly, but then the helm call fails.

```
$ echo "connecting to gcloud"
connecting to gcloud
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account ${GCLOUD_SERVACCT} --key-file ${GCLOUD_SERVACCT_KEY}
Activated service account credentials for: [gitlab-c292ecdff7c3bcd6dd4f68@octodemo-2802.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
$ gcloud config set project octodemo-2802
Updated property [core/project].
$ gcloud artifacts docker images list us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/octodemo-2802/octodemo-helm-repo
Listing items under project octodemo-2802, location us-west2, repository octodemo-helm-repo.
IMAGE                                                              DIGEST                                                                   CREATE_TIME          UPDATE_TIME
us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/octodemo-2802/octodemo-helm-repo/octodemo  sha256:ff4a6206e799a3a74a2f58d0c9dcb32219a12afac492967977063a91bc602045  2023-08-24T19:45:20  2023-08-24T19:45:20
$ echo "pull chart from artifact reg"
pull chart from artifact reg
$ helm pull oci://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/octodemo-2802/octodemo-helm-repo/octodemo@sha256:ff4a6206e799a3a74a2f58d0c9dcb32219a12afac492967977063a91bc602045 \ --version 1.0.0 \ --untar
Error: GET "https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/octodemo-2802/octodemo-helm-repo/octodemo/tags/list": GET "https://us-west2-docker.pkg.dev/v2/token?scope=repository%3Aoctodemo-2802%2Foctodemo-helm-repo%2Foctodemo%3Apull&service=us-west2-docker.pkg.dev": unexpected status code 403: denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/octodemo-2802/locations/us-west2/repositories/octodemo-helm-repo" (or it may not exist)
```

I'm lost on what I'm missing here. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case anyone else comes across this and is stuck, the issue was helm was relying on docker for the authentication, even though the service account had all the access needed and was connected. Also, the ci process was not a fan of the \ in the helm pull command, I've no idea why, but I kept getting "Error: non-absolute URLs should be in form of repo_name/path_to_chart, got: " errors. Once I removed the \ and placed it in-line, that cleared up. Another couple points, no need for export if using --untar with helm pull, and I'd recommend using the --untardir to specify where it exports to, even still, it has the image name as a subfolder of whatever you list, and that's import for the helm install/ upgrade. Finally, and this was based on my ignorance, just make sure all your cluster connection, auth, and helm deploy commands are in the same stage, since they run in different containers and will not recognize what another stage completed, this also means you either build an image with the basic loads for the services you need, use one from docker hub (where gitlab pulls from by default) or approach another way. (maybe theres another way to connect results from one stage to another, but that was my solution). Below is the updated stage:

```
 Deploy-Helm:
  stage: deploy
  image: kiwigrid/gcloud-kubectl-helm
  only: [dev-test]
  script:
    - echo "connecting to gcloud"
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account ${GCLOUD_SERVACCT} --key-file ${GCLOUD_SERVACCT_KEY}
    - gcloud config set project ${GCLOUD_PROJECT}
    - gcloud artifacts docker images list ${GCLOUD_REPO}
    - gcloud auth configure-docker us-west2-docker.pkg.dev
    - echo "pull chart from artifact reg"
    - helm pull oci://${GCLOUD_REPO} --version 0.1.0 --untar --untardir ./install
    - echo "Deploying Helm..."  
    - helm upgrade demotest ./install/octodemo -n demotest -f ./install/octodemo/values-test.yaml
```